# Material appeals purple when connecting emission shader

Tags: materials, emission, toon-shading

I'm trying to make a Emission Shader with Toon Shadow, but when i connect the Emission the shader my object appear to be purple but i'm not using any image texture. How should i fix this?[image]

Comment: That's because you connected the shaders (the green nodes) before the RGB and the ramp. The shaders should only be connected to the green sockets of the Material Output or to a Mix Shader node.

Comment: As @Vagabonk says, you plug a shader output into a color input, that does not work. Certain data connections can be mixed like vectors, colors and float values because they can be converted from one to another, like a single float can be applied to all three values of a vector, or the three values of a color or vector output can be averaged to be used in a single float input. But a shader output holds information on how a surface/volume should appear, these are not just simple numbers that can easily be split up in three values for a vector or color or merged somehow to a single float value.